# Swift performance and CustomStringConvertible protocol

Tags: ios, swift, performance

Here I'm trying to benchmark my `distinct` function, which receive array of random objects and return distinct array, by removing duplicates by `phoneNumber` attribute:
The strange thing happens when I implement `CustomStringConvertible` protocol for my `Person` class - the time spent for the task increases 3 times (see the elapsed time in very last line)

[image]

I never print any `Person` object so I don't see obvious reason for `description` var being accessed for 21000 times. Here is the result when I'm not implementing the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol:
[image]

What is the reason for the performance drop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet the playground is using the `description` property to display it in the results on the right side timeline view. Try running this outside of a playground and see what happens.

Comment: it would be great to have an option to disable the results section in playground...